# NullPointerException on going to another activity, android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-studio

***update***
I posted the new [LogCat](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file) reports, and I know there is something related to my second class named "Done" returning `null` which is causing this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rocrider.foodmenue/com.rocrider.foodmenue.Done}: java.lang.NullPointerException

I think the problem is somewhere in association of the class `Done`, with the button `BDone` and second_activity [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) file.

Just for information, I do give more than 0 values to food1amount and food2amount when my app starts. After I push the button "BDone", it crashes.

This app is supposed to be for waiters and waitresses to take orders from customers on tablets and then the program is supposed to make a list of foods with amounts ordered more than 0, "and later, not in this code" it is supposed to be able to send it to the printer in restaurant's kitchen.

My main class named MainActivity:

```
package com.rocrider.foodmenue;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button Bdone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bdone);
        Bdone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Done.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

My second class named Done, supposedly associated with second_activity.xml:

```
package com.rocrider.foodmenue;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Done extends MainActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
        Done();
    }

    public void BDone(){
        EditText Tfood1amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFood1Amount);
        EditText Tfood2amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFood2Amount);
        ListView lvlast = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LVfinal);
        final ArrayList<String> OrderList = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        int food1amount = 0;
        int food2amount = 0;
        food1amount = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Tfood1amount.getText()));
        food2amount = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Tfood2amount.getText()));

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.id.LVfinal,OrderList);
        lvlast.setAdapter(adapter);

        if(food1amount != 0){
            class alaki{
                public void adder(View v){
                    OrderList.add("Food1: ");
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        if(food2amount != 0){
            class alaki{
                public void adder(View v){
                    OrderList.add("Food2: ");
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My androidmanifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rocrider.foodmenue"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.rocrider.foodmenue.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Done"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Latest LogCat report:

```
09-29 10:40:58.976  15228-15228/com.rocrider.foodmenue E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rocrider.foodmenue/com.rocrider.foodmenue.Done}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.rocrider.foodmenue.Done.BDone(Done.java:37)
    at com.rocrider.foodmenue.Done.onCreate(Done.java:19)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
    ... 11 more
    09-29 10:40:58.980      118-136/? E/? Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: what is Done.java line 29?

Comment: Done.java is my second class which I tried to dedicate my second_activity.xml to it.

Comment: My advice is to learn the basics of OOP, then Java, then try to create an app.  Your knowledge is not yet good enough to succeed.

Comment: @Simon tnx for your advice, I'm trying to learn these by reading and trying to make small apps to learn also in practice. Any help about the question also would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your comment to Vang's answer tells me that you do not need help with the question.  You should take a step back and learn some more since any answer I can give you will not make sense to you.

Comment: I got the error public class Done extends MainActivity with public class Done extends Activity in your main class.

Comment: Hope now your activity able to start.

Comment: I'm going really crazy, it is still throwing me:
`09-28 12:34:15.550  10830-10830/com.rocrider.foodmenue E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rocrider.foodmenue/com.rocrider.foodmenue.Done}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); replace it with getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

Comment: Guys if you know some right way to do what I'm trying to do, I'd be more than happy to hear your advice and start over with a new project, as it seems nobody can find out what is really wrong with my code, I was wondering maybe there is some settings I might have messed up or something. Like always though, any help is more than appreciated. I really wanna know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @JoxTraex excuse me can you please tell me why my question is being on hold?
I included all the solutions everyone wrote here and also wrote that what was the result to that solution, I'm sure I have minimal understanding of the problem as I wrote it myself.
At least I suppose I deserve to know the reason for my question being on hold.

Comment: dear  First R0cRid3r, this question is on hold for the reason: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved". you gave here a huge blob of code and it shows that you probably doesn't have a clue about what went wrong. we need the relevant code only please

Comment: @NoIdeaForName Thank you very much for at least telling me the reason. People with your attitude of helping and guiding are really rare.
I know its either because of onCreate methods in my classes or android manifest, I posted the whole code, just to give a clear picture about my simple program, but if that is not the right way to post a question, a simple comment or edit suggestion could do the work. I don't see why my question had to be put on hold.
Tnx again for the feedback.

Comment: i wouldn't have voted to close it. having said that, i can see why it would bother other people... in anyway, if you didn't get the answer you need, you can think on where it went wrong, and post a new question with a little code and some explanations. i have very little understanding on android, but i'm sure the answer will be found soon enough

Comment: @FirstR0cRid3r: Where is line 1651 in your code?

Comment: @juergend Sorry if it sounds dumb, but how can I find that specific line? double click doesn't work and I couldn't find search.

Comment: @FirstR0cRid3r: In whatever tool you program, you can display code line numbers in the editor. Look for it in the options of your tool.

Comment: btw, do you guys see anything wrong with the way I'm trying to add items into my ListView on second activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go through the following scenario. You're calling `Done` Activity so in its `onCreate` method you're calling `BDone()` function. In that function,

```
EditText Tfood1amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFood1Amount);
EditText Tfood2amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFood2Amount);
ListView lvlast = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LVfinal);
final ArrayList<String> OrderList = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
int food1amount = 0;
int food2amount = 0;
food1amount = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Tfood1amount.getText()));
food2amount = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Tfood2amount.getText()));
```

These lines might be throwing `NullPointerException`, because you're initialising two EditTexts. The problem is in `food1amount` & `food2amount`; you're getting text from EditText and parsing it. But you just initialized those EditTexts and getting text from it. That is why you're getting **null**. And you're trying to parse null, so that it's showing a `NullPointerException`. Sorry that I can't post neat code as I'm on a mobile. I hope you understood.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution in fact resolved my issue and solved the error. It works without error as I put `EditText Tfood2amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFood2Amount);
    ListView lvlast = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LVfinal);
food1amount = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Tfood1amount.getText()));
    food2amount = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Tfood2amount.getText()));`
inside my BDone onClick method but now when I push the button, the list is empty, but I think now that I know what was causing that error, I can soon solve this new problem.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: food1amount = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Tfood1amount.getText()));    ---->> Can be simplified to Integer.parseInt(Tfood1amount.getText().toString())

Answer (score 2):

In your second activity, add a call to `BDone` in your onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
    BDone();
}
```

In class `Main`, replace `public class Done extends MainActivity` with `public class Done extends Activity`.

Try this whole code:

#### MainActivity class

```
package com.rocrider.foodmenue;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Done done = new Done();
        Button Bdone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bdone);
        Bdone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Done.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

#### Done class

```
package com.rocrider.foodmenue;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Done extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
        BDone();
    }

    public void BDone(){
        EditText Tfood1amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFood1Amount);
        EditText Tfood2amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFood2Amount);
        ListView lvlast = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LVfinal);
        final ArrayList<String> OrderList = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        int food1amount = 0;
        int food2amount = 0;
        food1amount = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Tfood1amount.getText()));
        food2amount = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Tfood2amount.getText()));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.id.LVfinal,OrderList);
        lvlast.setAdapter(adapter);
        if(food1amount != 0){
            class alaki{
                public void adder(View v){
                    OrderList.add("Food1: ");
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        if(food2amount != 0){
            class alaki{
                public void adder(View v){
                    OrderList.add("Food2: ");
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this, nothing changed. I also removed done.BDone(); from    `code Bdone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                done.BDone();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Done.class));

            }
        }); `
and it threw me that error:`code java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rocrider.foodmenue/com.rocrider.foodmenue.Done}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @FirstR0cRid3r is both of ur activity in same package

Comment: Yep, at `package com.rocrider.foodmenue;`

Comment: On main class tells me that cannot resolve symbol activity_main and on Done class tells me cannot resolve symbol Activity, and cannot resolve method "onCreate(android.os.Bundle)" and setcontentview and findViewbyid and also cannot resolve constructor arrayadapter :(
Really thanks though, for trying to help. it means a great deal to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the manual creation of the second activity, because onCreate doesn't get called, and you get a NullPoinerException. `BDone()` should called from onCreate in the *Done* activity.

Comment: I didn't quite understand, you mean I had to create BDone() method inside onCreate method? cause onCreate is itself a method and I have to make a class inside so I can make another method inside onCreate.

Can you please clarify your answer a bit?
Tnx

Answer (score 0):

In OnClick in MainActivity, you are calling `done.BDone();` which is causing the error. Because at that time the layout has not been inflated in the Done activity, so findViewById is throwing an error. Call `BDone` from onCreate in the Done activity.

In the main class, do this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button Bdone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bdone);
        Bdone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Done.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And in the Done class, do this:

```
public class Done extends MainActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
        BDone();
    }
```

Comment: this solved that problem but throw me another error:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rocrider.foodmenue/com.rocrider.foodmenue.Done}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I have edited the answer a bit. did it not work? post the crash logs you are getting after it.

Comment: `09-28 12:19:34.609  10537-10537/com.rocrider.foodmenue E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rocrider.foodmenue/com.rocrider.foodmenue.Done}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)`

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your super class of Done activity is `MainActivity`. It should be `Activity`.

Replace

```
public class Done extends MainActivity
```

to

```
public class Done extends Activity
```

Comment: Tnx a lot but it is still throwing me:
`09-28 12:34:15.550  10830-10830/com.rocrider.foodmenue E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rocrider.foodmenue/com.rocrider.foodmenue.Done}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score -2):

```
  Button bdone = (Button)findViewById(id of button);
  bdone.setOnClickListener(new OnlickListener)
  {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view)
      {
          //Code here
      }
  }
```

Comment: How is this an answer?  What did you change?  Why?  What should the OP learn from this?